# Adding two arrays for a total

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class SeatCalculator {

static void display() {

    int AdultPrice = 6;
    int KidPrice = 3;       
    String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        System.out.print("||              ID                ||  FirstName  ||  LastName ||  TelNum  ||  Adults  ||  Kids  ||  Total Price  ||  Total");

        String[] SetBooking1 = new String[4];           //Creats an array called SetBooking and gives it 8 identifiers. 
        SetBooking1[0] = uniqueID;
        SetBooking1[1] = "James"; 
        SetBooking1[2] = "hellier"; 
        SetBooking1[3] = "07707659810";

         int[] SetBookingValues = new int[4];
         SetBookingValues[0] = 3;
         SetBookingValues[1] = 4;
         SetBookingValues[2] = SetBookingValues[0] * AdultPrice + SetBookingValues[1] * KidPrice;
         SetBookingValues[3] = SetBookingValues[0] + SetBookingValues[1];

        String[] SetBooking2 = new String[4];           //Creats an array called SetBooking and gives it 8 identifiers. 
        SetBooking2[0] = uniqueID;
        SetBooking2[1] = "Kayleigh"; 
        SetBooking2[2] = "ray"; 
        SetBooking2[3] = "07706541234";

         int[] SetBookingValues2 = new int[4];
         SetBookingValues2[0] = 2;
         SetBookingValues2[1] = 3;
         SetBookingValues2[2] = SetBookingValues2[0] * AdultPrice + SetBookingValues2[1] * KidPrice;
         SetBookingValues2[3] = SetBookingValues2[0] + SetBookingValues2[1];



    System.out.println("\n"+Arrays.toString(SetBooking1) + Arrays.toString(SetBookingValues));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SetBooking2) + Arrays.toString(SetBookingValues2));

   System.out.print("\nCurrent revenue gained from booking: "); 
   System.out.print("\nCurrent seats left: "  );

}

}
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate `SetBookingValues` value [3] and `SetBookingValues2` value [3] in order to keep a running total, essentially it's adding the passengers and then a parameter will be set ensuring no more than 32 seats can be booked.

Comment: What's the current and the expected outcome?

Comment: Why are you using String- and int-arrays instead of own classes that hold the data in meaningful way (i.e. containing specific members for first name, last name, etc.). That would also let vanish the problem you're currently facing.

Comment: @Lothar How do you mean? Don't mean to be incompetent but rather new to java.

Comment: @KarlRichter That I cannot add the two totals listed above into a system.out, the idea is to let the user know how many spaces are left. The current outcome just shows the two arrays but that's it.

Comment: What do you mean "8 identifiers"?

Comment: **Use objects, not arrays.** 

One of the reasons for Object-Oriented Programming such as Java is to avoid the clumsiness you’ve encountered with mere arrays to represent business entities.

Define a class `Booking` to retain the passenger name, telephone, kid vs adult, price paid.

Define another class `Voyage` that includes a collection of `Booking` objects. This class holds the current price for adult and kid, and the seating capacity. This class can tell you if it is full or not, and total amount paid by all bookings.